# Concat String with variable value to form New Variable

Tags: r, variables, concatenation

I have to make dynamic variable which store different value as given in pseudo code

```
for(i in 1:30)
 "Day"+i <- sqldf("select * from call_details where day ="+i)
```

Is it possible in R or not and if possible then how? I just able to concat the string (using [paste](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/paste.html)) which store the concated string as character but couldn't able to store value on it. Also I could not able to find out how to pass variable on sql query statement.

Comment: For inserting variables into the select string see Example 5 on the sqldf home page: http://sqldf.googlecode.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be storing similar data in a structure like a `list` instead of free floating variables. This might seem odd at first, but trust me when I say this will prevent a lot of grief further down the line. E.g.:

```
Days <- lapply(1:30,function(i) sqldf(paste("select * from call_details where day =",i)) )
```

Then you can access the components of the list like:

```
Days[[1]]
Days[[2]]
etc etc
```

Instead of using `day1` `day2` etc etc

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into `assign` to be able to construct variables in the way you're describing. In general, you can use `paste` but you connect strings with commas, not pluses.

Something like the following:

```
for(i in 1:30)
    assign(paste0("Day",i), sqldf(paste("select * from call_details where day =",i)))
```